# Bootstrap3 form-horizontal renders fine on larger screens but not mobile

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I can't seem to figure out why bootstrap 3 doesn't seem to render form-horizontal correctly on smaller screen sizes.

The labels should all be right aligned (not left) and their vertical alignment should be baseline so the text lines up with the inputs.

This does not work when rendered in mobile mode in Chrome on the "Nexus 5" device nor on a true mobile device.

Any ideas as to what I missed / got wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body style="margin-top: 20px">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">My Panel Heading</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-xs-5">Test Label</label>
                                <div class="controls col-xs-7">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="My Test Value A"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-xs-5">Really Long Test Label</label>
                                <div class="controls col-xs-7">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="My Test Value B"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/z4kjjbfe/) what you want ?

Comment: You have only given `col-xs-5` meaning it will take 5 grids only in xs screens and if there is not enough space on the right it will wrap to next line

Comment: col-xs-* never wraps on any screen size (@Bhargav), use col-sm-, col-md- or col-lg- instead

Comment: yes you need to use the col-sm col-md properties

Comment: @Hazard The alignment CSS should already be in there as it right aligns as-is on larger screen sizes.

Comment: @Bhargav I am already using the sm, md and lg column sizes as can be seen in the div that is parent to the panel.  The panel parent sizes correctly in the 4 bootstrap media sizes.  The col-xs-5 on the label and the col-xs-7 on the input establish the ratio.  Is this not sufficient? Adding col-sm, col-md and col-lg classes don't even come into effect at the xs size I am having an issue with.

Answer (score 1):

Override bootstrap 3.3.6 defaults with this:

```
@media (min-width: 1px) {
  .form-horizontal .control-label {
    padding-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use col-sm/md/lg to define the column/s

Col-xs-* is for mobile devices correct, but will not display what you want properly.

Comment: Why won't it display what I want correctly?  That is what I am asking.  Also, I am using the col-sm/md/lg classes in the div that is parent to the panel.